# How to check if the word 2013 content is modified using office 2013 javascript API

Tags: office-js

I have a task pane with save button in word 2013. I would like to know whether the document is modified before enabling the task pane save button. Is there a possibility to check dirty?
I can see there is an event for selection change but its not really perfect to check dirty.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct way to tell whether the document has been modified since the last save. However, there are several workarounds that may help for your particular use case.

In Word 2013, the [getFileAsync API](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getfileasync) is available to retrieve the entire contents of the file. You could retrieve the file contents once when you start the add-in and again when you want to check whether the document has changed.

```
Office.context.document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Compressed, {}, 
    function(result){
        fileObject = result.value;
    }
);
```

The disadvantages here are that large files will take lot of memory to store and a lot of bandwidth to retrieve. The bandwidth problem can't be solved with this workaround, but the storage problem can be solved by saving a [checksum](http://codepen.io/ImagineProgramming/post/checksum-algorithms-in-javascript-checksum-js-engine) on the file object instead of saving the file itself.

Alternatively, if you're using more recent versions of Word, you can make use of the [ParagraphCollection object](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/paragraphcollection) to see whether particular paragraphs have been modified or added/removed. The advantage here is smaller bandwidth consumption, but the disadvantage is that it won't detect every single type of change like the first workaround does (eg. adding text in the footer).

Comment: I did try this approach it was successful but there is a problem . File byte size changes even when the document is not modifed. The file size is not consistent.